# Any way to disable view restrictions being displayed to admins in django cms?

Tags: django-cms

I'm trying to configure a very simple user in django cms and don't want to confuse them with view permissions. Is there a config setting to change this in 2.2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One possible way may be to drop your users is_superuser status and then grant them (within the Users admin page) any rights but no rights for ''cms:permissions''.